# Using %n% inline variable as %n%-1 with Iterate Feature Classes iterator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, union

I am new to ArcGIS Pro and have just a "Basic" license. I have no Python coding experience.

I am trying to make a ModelBuilder tool that will Union multiple feature classes (as little as two but maybe up to 20).  Since I only have the Basic license, I can only Union two feature classes at a time.

When I perform this manually I set up a bracket like this:

[image]

I union ShapeW to ShapeX to form Union 1. I then Union ShapeY to ShapeZ to form Union 2. I then Union 1 and 2 to form my final Union 3.  With more shapes, my bracket just expands to more levels.

For my ModelBuilder I am using the following flow:

- Iterate Feature Classes
- If %n% <> 0 then go to Branch 1
- If %n% = 0 then go to Branch 2
- Both branches are similar in that they remove fields, delete rows etc. the difference is that Branch 2, exports the current Feature Class as Union0.
- I would like to have Branch 1 "Union" the current feature class (%n%) and the previous feature (%n%-1).  So if %n% =1 it would Union the current feature class (ShapeX) and the previous %n%-1 (Union0).

The inline variable %n% keeps a count of the iteration.  I would like use %n%-1 as an inline substitute variable.  Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You could use the model only tool Calculate value to return the value %n% - 1.

Comment: Thanks.  Does Calculate Value change with each iteration?  How do I bring that value back into the model for use as an inline variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Calculate Value with the expression `"Union"+str(%n%-1)` to identify the name of the feature class created in a previous iteration. This is just the concatenation of the known part of the feature class name (`Union` in your example) with the iteration count `%n% - 1` wrapped in the Python `str()` function which converts the count integer to a string value.

Comment: Thanks!!  That was it.